# unnamed function object as parameter

Tags: c++, binary-tree, traversal

I am constructing a binary tree, and I have the following function headers included in my binTree class:

```
public:
    ...
    void inorder(void(*)(T&));                // inorder traversal of tree
    ...
private:
    ...
    void inorder(Node<T>*, void(*)(T&));      // private version of inorder()
    ...
```

However, every time I go to compile my code, I get an error from the following implementation:

```
template<class T>
void binTree<T>::inorder(void(*)(T&) f) {
    inorder(root,f);
}
```

It tells me that there should be a comma before `f`. If I leave off the f, it will compile as long as I don't make the call to the private version of inorder. How do I properly make the call to the private version of inorder?

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't it be `void(*f) (T&)`?

Comment: ahhhhh yes, that was my problem...been coding for too many hours my brain is fried